# How do i get the block to go below the screen so i can scroll to it instead of it being at the bottom of the screen

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
   <div class="topbar"></div>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="new.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <header class="headings">
   <h1 align="center">Header</h1>
   <h3 align="center">smaller header</h3>
  </header>
  <form class="form">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" autofocus/></br>
    <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"></br>
    <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
  </form>
  <div class="bottombar">
    <h1 align="center"><ins>About Us</ins></h1>
    <p>blah blah blah</br>blah blah blah</br>blah blah blah</br></p>
  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

and this is the CSS for the bar at the bottom

```
.bottombar{
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #FDFEFE;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 3px #888888;
}
```

this is the output at the moment

[image]

The problem is that the About-Us bar at the bottom is sticking out of the bottom and showing up on the screen. I want it to go just below the screen so I can scroll to it instead.

Comment: did you try `margin-top` already, on another position?, a `position fixed` element cant be out of view and scrolled to again, fixed stays in place so if its not visible, it will remain that way i quote w3schools `position: fixed;
An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used to position the element.

A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.`

Comment: You shouldn’t use position fixed, instead position absolute, and use top: 100vh instead of bottom: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will this do?

tip: try see in expanded view, or after expanding snippet, for full view.

```css
.container {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}

section {height: 100%;display:block;background: yellow;height: 100vh;text-align:center;}

.bottombar{
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #FDFEFE;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px 3px #888888;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <section>
    <header class="headings">
      <h1 align="center">Header</h1>
      <h3 align="center">smaller header</h3>
    </header>
    <form>
      <h1>Login</h1>
      <input type="text" name="Username" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>         <br/>
      <input type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"><br/>
      <input type="submit" name="" value="submit">
    </form>
  </section>
  
  <div class="bottombar">
      <h1><ins>About Us</ins></h1>
      <p>blah blah blah<br/>blah blah blah<br/>blah blah blah<br/></p>
  </div>
  
</div>
```